# PHP isset(null['?'])

Tags: php, isset

The `isset()` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) clearly tells me that

> `isset()` only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the `defined()` function.

---

So, `echo (isset(null)) ? 'YES' : 'NO';` is giving the fatal error as excepted;

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

---

**Question**;

Why does `isset(null['?'])` does not trow the same error;

```
echo (isset(null['?'])) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

> NO

---

I'm expecting the same error, since `isset()` can't be used on non-variables.

I'm aware that

```
<?php

$x = NULL;
$x['?'] = 'hi';
echo gettype($x); // array
```

will set `$x` to an array, however, (as expected) `echo @gettype(null['1']);` stays null?

Comment: I understand why my question is voted as [duplicate], however, those questions are 6-7 years old, without any solids answers, and there is not much over PHP7.4. [One comment](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/notice-for-non-valid-array-container) says that it should throw a notice, but it's not? Any

Comment: This is fine - think of the compiler - you are passing `null` to `isset` than after null is created on the stack its mutated to an array with a key '?' which points to null. so at the end its exactly as `isset(["?" => null]["?"]) // FALSE`